# Minus sign in rotated triangles in triangulated categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $T$ be a [triangulated category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_category) and

$$ X \xrightarrow{u} Y \xrightarrow{v} Z \xrightarrow{w} X[1]$$

an exact triangle (or distinguished triangle). [**TR 2**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulated_category#TR_2) implies that then the two rotated triangles

$$ Y \xrightarrow{v} Z \xrightarrow{w} X[1] \xrightarrow{-u[1]} Y[1] $$

and

$$ Z[-1] \xrightarrow{-w[-1]} X \xrightarrow{u} Y \xrightarrow{v} Z $$

are also exact.
Is there any reason/motivation for the appearance of the minus signs for $u[1]$ and $w[-1]$? What is the reason to introduce them? Grows it out of a geometric analogy?

Comment: This axiom just codifies what happens in explicit examples. Consider the case of the derived category of a ring, with the explicit mapping cone construction, and compute what happens. Once you check it on your own, you won't forget it.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: maybe I understand what you mean. In derived category of ring (ie the category
we obtain after passing from category of chain complexes of modules
to to it's homotopy category, we can wlog asume that $Z=Cone(u)$ and
that $X[1]$ is a some "kind of suspension" of $X$. And what we want 
is that in every partial sequence consisting of four consecutive 
members in the distinguished sequence

$$ ... \to X \xrightarrow{u} Y \xrightarrow{v} Z \xrightarrow{w} X[1] \to ...$$

Comment: is *homotopic* to $A \xrightarrow{f} B \to Cone(f) \to Suspension(A)$.
And if we consider the part 
$Y \xrightarrow{v} Z \xrightarrow{w} X[1] \xrightarrow{?} Y[1]$ then the explicite calculation must show that 
it can be only homotopic to 
$Y \xrightarrow{v} Z \to Cone(v) \to Suspension(Y)$ if functor
$?$ in right arrow is $-u[1]$; in other words there is no such
homotopy if $?$ was $u[1]$. That's your point, right?

Comment: Well $X[1]$ _is_ already the suspension, and we shouldn't mistake homotopies for isomorphisms in the homotopy category, but apart from that, the idea in your second comment is OK, that's what you can prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\mathcal{D},T)$ be an additive category with an autoequivalence $T:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{D}$. One could theoretically modify the TR2 axiom to instead require that $X\xrightarrow{u}Y\xrightarrow{v}Z\xrightarrow{w}TX$ is distinguished if and only if $ Y\xrightarrow{v}Z\xrightarrow{w}TX\xrightarrow{Tu}TZ$ is distinguished, thereby deleting the minus sign. As far as I can tell, up to deletion of certain minus signs in some formulas, nothing would change in the theory and existing results of triangulated categories. Nonetheless, this way *we would be unable to equip* $K(\mathcal{A})$—the homotopy category of cochain complexes with terms in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$—*with the structure of a triangulated category*. Why? Well, because in $K(\mathcal{A})$ what actually happens is that a triangle $X\xrightarrow{u}Y\xrightarrow{v}Z\xrightarrow{w}X[1]$ is distinguished if and only if $ Y\xrightarrow{v}Z\xrightarrow{w}X[1]\xrightarrow{-u[1]}Z[1]$ is distinguished, and note that it does not make sense to define $T=-[1]$, since this is not a functor (it does not preserve identities nor compositions, unless we are working mod $2$; thanks to F. Muro for pointing this out in a comment).

In one sentence: the minus sign in TR2 is because we want to apply our theory to the primary examples of triangulated categories, $K(\mathcal{A})$ and $D(\mathcal{A})=K(\mathcal{A})[\text{qis}^{-1}]$. One could ask now: *then why do d.t.'s behave this way in these categories?* (I.e., with the need to introduce a minus sign after rotation to get again a d.t.) The answer is: look at how one proves in $K(\mathcal{A})$ that $X\xrightarrow{u}Y\xrightarrow{v}Z\xrightarrow{w}X[1]$ distinguished implies $ Y\xrightarrow{v}Z\xrightarrow{w}X[1]\xrightarrow{-u[1]}Z[1]$ distinguished. This is done in the second paragraph of the proof of [014S](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014S), but here's the argument anyway: by definition, if $X\xrightarrow{u}Y\xrightarrow{v}Z\xrightarrow{w}X[1]$ is distinguished, then it is isomorphic to a triangle of the form $K\xrightarrow{f}L\xrightarrow{i}C(f)\xrightarrow{-p}K[1]$. Thus we get an isomorphism of triangles
\begin{gather*}
\require{HTML}
Y\xrightarrow{v}Z\xrightarrow{w}X[1]\xrightarrow{-u[1]}Z[1]\\
\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\cong}\\
L\xrightarrow{i}C(f)\xrightarrow{-p}K[1]\xrightarrow{-f[1]}L[1]\\
\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg)}{\cong}\\
L\xrightarrow{i}C(f)\xrightarrow{p}K[1]\xrightarrow{f[1]}L[1]
\end{gather*}
But the last triangle is the one arising from a term-wise split s.e.s. of complexes, [014O](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014O). Hence it is a d.t., by [014L](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/014L).